# Java 8 reference to a static method vs. instance method

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, method-reference

say I have the following code

```
public class A {
    int x;
    public boolean is() {return x%2==0;}
    public static boolean is (A a) {return !a.is();}
}
```

and in another class...

```
List<A> a = ...
a.stream().filter(b->b.isCool());
a.stream().filter(A::is); 
//would be equivalent if the static method is(A a) did not exist
```

the question is how do I refer to the instance method version using the A::is type notation?  Thanks a lot

Comment: You mean how to invoke instance method if both those methods are there?

Comment: The compiler error says: "reference to is is ambiguous, both method is(A) in A and method is() in A match". So clearly the compiler cannot decide here. I bet your best choice is to change the notation to a lambda expression to make it evident.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your example, both the static and the non-static method are applicable for the target type of the filter method. In this case, you can't use a method reference, because the ambiguity can not be resolved. See §15.13.1 [Compile-Time Declaration of a Method Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.13.1) for details, in particular the following quote and the examples below:

> If the first search produces a static method, and no non-static method is applicable [..], then the compile-time declaration is the result of the first search. Otherwise, if no static method is applicable [..], and the second search produces a non-static method, then the compile-time declaration is the result of the second search. **Otherwise, there is no compile-time declaration.**

In this case, you can use a lambda expression instead of a method reference:

```
a.stream().filter(item -> A.is(item));
```

The above rule regarding the search for static and non-static methods is somewhat special, because it doesn't matter, which method is the better fit. Even if the static method would take an *Object* instead of *A*, it's still ambiguous. For that reason, I recommend as a general guideline: If there are several methods with the same name in a class (including methods inherited from base classes):

- All methods should have the same access modifiers,
- All methods should have the same final and abstract modifiers,
- And all methods should have the same static modifier

Answer (score -7):

We can not use not static methods or non-global methods by using className::methodName notation. 
If you want to use methods of a particular class you have to have an instance of the class.

```
So if you want to access is() method then you can use : 
A a = new A();
a.is();
OR 
(new A()).is();
```

Thanks.

Comment: [This is about Java-8 Method reference.](http://java8.in/java-8-method-references/)