# Function interface as function reference

Tags: java, function, java-8, method-reference

```
public static void main(String o[]) {
    Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    map.put("a", 1);
    map.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue)).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Above code builds and runs perfectly but it shouldn't. Comparator.comparing takes a function reference and only those methods which takes one argument and returns one argument can be mapped on this. But in above code getValue is mapped and works fine but it doesn't take any parameter. Code should give build issue but doesn't. Is there any issue with my concept?

Comment: See [Difference between method reference Bound Receiver and UnBound Receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35914775/2711488)

Comment: Or simply said, `Entry::getValue` is the same as `entry -> entry.getValue()`. But you can replace `Comparator.comparing(Entry::getValue)` with `Entry.comparingByValue()`, by the way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The single argument `comparing` method:

```
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> comparing(
        Function<? super T, ? extends U> keyExtractor)
```

takes a `Function<? super T, ? extends U>` argument, which is a functional interface that contains a single method that takes a argument of one type and returns a value of some other type.

`Entry::getValue` takes an argument of one type (`Map.Entry<String, Integer>` in your example) and returns a value of some other type (`Integer` in your example). Therefore it matches the `Function` functional interface.

> But in above code getValue is mapped and works fine but it doesn't take any parameter.

Yes it does - each `Map.Entry` element taken from the `Stream` serves as an argument of the `apply()` method of the `Function` interface.

Perhaps this will clarify:

```
Function<Map.Entry<Integer, String>, String> func = Map.Entry::getValue;
```

The `getValue()` method of `Map.Entry` can be viewed as a `Function` that accepts a `Map.Entry` instance and return the value of that instance (returned by calling `getValue()` on that instance).

Comment: I can't see any method in import java.util.Map.Entry class with name "getValue" which takes an argument, but it still works fine.

Comment: @UmairZahid The argument is the `Map.Entry` instance on which `getValue()` is executed. The `getValue()` method doesn't have an argument.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, your method reference is an instance method, rather than a static one, so instead of for each item calling and using the value of:

`Entry.getValue(item)`

It uses

`item.getValue()` 
[JavaDoc]
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#getValue())

so it acts as the lambda: `p -> p.getValue()`, converting an entry into its value for comparison, as it has one argument and returns one value without throwing exceptions it can implement `Function<Entry<String, Integer>, Integer>`.

If both a static and instance method exists you cannot use a method reference, as per this question: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23051879/java-8-reference-to-a-static-method-vs-instance-method)

[Worked example](https://tio.run/##fZDBTsMwDIbveQprp0yISHBcAYnDDkhw6hOYLtvcpUmUuIMJ7dmLm67SpCFyiWL/@fz/bvGI9yFa324Ow0BdDImhlaLpmZx5TQlPuVI3jXfKXCkV@09HDTQOc4YPJA8/SgFcypmR5ToG2sD6G7vo7IMuKmLbLUULcupTlpcJPZuYyLPzelFPPxdwN0krUZ6vyAVpJ@Sj/o/05sWFb2xh8Z7yDevaZSfm9JY8OqhZEDtjDGDa5XnEmPtpjPBSjGV4hmlHBvPY095@lUXopQwqX4rObENaY7Mv8VereRvFzN@SOd3F71kNwy8)

Comment: Even if it uses instance for calling method, method signature should be the same. I don't think it omits argument at runtime. WDYT?

Comment: Static method references are called with the instance, whereas instance method references are called on the instance

Comment: Agreed but the implementation can change based on instance or static cases, method signature remains same.

Comment: I have added a link to a worked example, both reference types have the same syntax, but only the static one has an argument